# Eclipse searching files in specific package

Tags: eclipse, search

I am attempting to strip out my Log.i Log.d etc code in eclipse.  I have used them liberally. I can find them by <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and using the *File Search* tab. Once I can filter the results to a certain package I plan on doing a replace with a blank string.

I check the *Regular Expression* checkbox.
In the *Containing text:* field I use `Log\..*;`

This gets every single Log line of code in the workspace (At least I think workspace, because there is currently 1 project in the workspace)

How can I get this search to only search within a certain package (ie com.example.so.is.super.cool)

I assume this is in the *File name patterns* field and I have attempted:

```
.*super.*
*super*
super
```

Please let me know if there is a pattern I can enter in *File name patterns* that narrows the search down for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how:

1. Select the package in Package Explorer
2. On the Search > File Search panel: Specify regular expression, set **Scope** to "Selected resources"
3. Press **Search**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sri, it works great. I am guessing the File name pattern does not check against the relative or absolute path, just the file name.

Comment: Apparently not.  See description of **File name patterns** at http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-45.htm